# Is the OwnerId field in the Report object a polymorphic key or not?

Tags: soql, polymorphism

Is the OwnerId field in the Report object a polymorphic key or not?

So the OwnerId field in the Report object can be either a reference to a Folder, Account, or User, doesn't this make it a polymorphic key? And if so, why doesn't this work?

```
SELECT Name, Description, OwnerId.Name FROM Report WHERE OwnerId.Type = 'Report'
```

This is the doc I'm referring to for polymorphic keys: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#soql_polymorph_keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OwnerId is not a polymorphic key here.

The query wont work and we cannot apply that query .Also found that the ownerId is not a foreign key.

Consider the screenshot below of Report Object in eclipse
[image]

We see above that OwnerId is not foreign key also only filterable and its not updadtable or creatable

Consider same from Event Object

[image]

The foreign key is who and its creatable and updatable as well hence can be used in Polymorphic queries and also can be filtered on TYPE.

Comment: This is not working. Here's a screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/coDbG.png

Comment: It should, looks like a bug

Comment: Owner.Type you have missed

Comment: @MohithKumar it's in the WHERE clause

Comment: Change that to owner.folder.Type and try for curiousity

Comment: @MohithKumar that didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have api 26.0 and subscribed to this feature?

Comment: @MohithKumar I don't think a query like this is related the the TYPEOF SOQL polymorphism in dev preview api 26

Comment: @fourq  SELECT Id, Who.Id, Who.Type
FROM Task
WHERE Who.Type='Contact'   try this and see if this works atleast then we can say its bug

Comment: @MohithKumar that SOQL works fine

Comment: @fourq Updated the answer and good learning.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.  First if you're reference fields on a parent object you'll want to use the relationship name.

```
SELECT Owner.name FROM Report WHERE Owner.Type = 'Report'
```

Second, based on the [report docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_report.htm) the owner field on a report refers only to user who created the report.

Third, Owner is a Name object, which is polymorphic.  For a list of fields you can reference for any name object see the [Name docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_name.htm).

Comment: I am currently using the OwnerId to grab the folder names successfully.

Screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/vXOet.png (This screen shot is a shot of SSMS using DBamp to create the SOQL, but regardless you can see the fields and objects taht are being used)

Comment: @Ralph I have updated the answer may be you would go through once .It was good learning